# Can BUILD files have arbitrary file extensions?

Tags: bazel

I am aware that bazel accepts both [BUILD and BUILD.bazel](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4517) as valid filenames.

The android tools seem to also have a [BUILD.tools](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/android/BUILD.tools) file.

In general, does bazel have any restrictions for a BUILD file's extension? For example, could i have BUILD.generated to delineate generate BUILD files from non-generated BUILD files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.tools` extension is part of building Bazel itself. From the perspective of Bazel, it's just any ordinary file. It gets picked up here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/bbc8ed16aee07c3ba9321d58aa4c0ffc55fa2ba9/tools/android/BUILD#L197

then eventually gets processed here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/c816b89a2224c3c318f1228755ef41c53975f45c/src/create_embedded_tools.py#L74

For the use case you mention, one way to go about it is to generate a `.bzl` file with a meaningful name that contains a macro that you can call from a `BUILD` or `BUILD.bazel` file. That way you can separate the generated rules from manually maintained rules. This is similar to how generate_workspace works: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/generate-workspace.html

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm then, any `BUILD` with non-standard file extension will need to later be renamed to `BUILD` or `BUILD.bazel`?

The generate-workspace approach, i.e. loading a `bzl` file, isn't necessarily ideal for the situation I am dealing with. Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: Following up on this question. How could I modify Bazel itself so it can understand different file extensions? For example, I would like to teach Bazel to consume BUILD files with the file extension BUILD.generated.

Comment: Looks like it's here: https://source.bazel.build/bazel/+/02a6e0f8ac34a4ca44cad6c8b2eba81645da10e4:src/tools/skylark/java/com/google/devtools/skylark/skylint/DependencyAnalyzer.java;l=43

Comment: Thank you Alex! I will try this out to see if I need to hack Bazel in any other locations. This also seems to be relevant: https://source.bazel.build/bazel/+/02a6e0f8ac34a4ca44cad6c8b2eba81645da10e4:src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/packages/BuildFileName.java;l=27